# Why did the TIFF that I added to ArcGIS Pro turn blue and how do I make it greyscale?

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, geotiff-tiff

I added a black and white TIFF that I want to use to create a basemap to a project in ArcGIS Pro. When I look at the layer, it turned a light blue color.

Why is this so and how do I make it grayscale?

Answer (score 2):

Rasters are just a grid of numbers - they don't inherently have colors attached to them. It sounds like the symbology of your raster defaulted to something different from what you were expecting. [Trying selecting a different colormap or band combination under the Appearance tab for your raster layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/raster-display-ribbon.htm).

Comment: That was it! It was a 30 second fix.  Wow, I need to ask questions on here a lot sooner...